Open another workbook using vba as read-write
I have two workbooks. We'll just say Template and Database
I want to use Template to open Database and dump stuff.
But I also want database to be read only if someone goes to just open database directly.
Is there a way to make it read only unless it’s opened using the macro in Template?
Can I pass a variable to it? If variable is found, then set to write mode if it’s not, then open as read only etc?
I've tried something along these lines:
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\...")

Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!ProcessArgument", argumentValue

And then in the database file, I was going to do read only unless argumentValue is True, but it seems the issue is the workbook is opened before it actually gets to the Application.Run line.
Appreciate any input. have spent hours trying to find different options.

You could have a shortcut to the file as read-only but that doesn't prevent people from opening it from the File-menu in Excel or going to the original location and opening it there.

Hello, open the Database workbook manually. File - Save As - then select "Tools" near the bottom right, then "General Options". Check mark the box "Read Only Recommended" then create a password. However, if you go this route, you will need to use the password in your Template VBA code when opening Database.
